# How to change my string to an int for us of supplying to socket

Tags: c++, string, int, atoi

I have an *.ini file with the following

```
[Settings]
Server=server.myserver.com
Port=6500
```

I am using theSimpleIni library. Now my problem is, that I can grab both variables easily enough from the ini. However, when supplying the Port to my socket it is not in a integer. Simplified code version to work with. Ultimately I am having trouble turning sPort into an integer so that I can assign it to int Port.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int Port;
  string sPort="6500";
    Port += atoi(sPort.c_str());
    cout<<sPort + "\n";
    cout<<Port;
c.conn(ini.GetValue("Settings","Server","") , Port);

}
```

I've tried stoi() and it did not work. I've tried atoi() as above and it atleast runs, but returns a random number other than 6500. 6500 is the magic number i need for the port. Anyone have any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: atoi() ltoi(), sscanf(), stoi() and much other..

Comment: Use stoi(), stol(), stod(), and so on

Answer (score 3):

The `Port` variable should be initialized (to `0`). If it's not, it gets a random value.

Or just use `=` instead of `+=`.

`std::stoi` is C++11 feature, you may not have it in your compiler version.

Comment: Awesome sauce...That worked wonderfully. Thanks for the quick reply. Definately the best answer.!!!

Comment: It is the only answer, yes, it is the best. Please consider accepting it if it works for you.